# Embarcadero RAD Studio : How to dock component palette

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have undocked component palette in Embarcadero RAD Studio.
And can not find a way how to dock it back.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Drag and drop doesn't work ? Just tested undocking and docking back with the mouse in 10.3 Rio

Answer (score 2):

I did it at last!

The problem was that there was not turned on the option "Auto drag docking" in the Tools -> Options -> Environment options.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drag it by its title bar towards another docked panel, and a highlight will appear to show where it will go. For instance if you drag it towards the bottom of the file explorer it will show a highlight and then sit under it.

Here's a screenshot which shows how it looks when I do that on RAD Studio 2007, although it may be different with your version. You can't see the cursor in the screenshot but it's near the bottom of the blue area.

[Tool Palette screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOfN3.png)